# How to run a simple Selenium automation test with FireFox in Mac OS and Eclipse

Tags: java, macos, selenium, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Im having an issue with running automation test with Selenium in Firefox adding the Geckodriver to my Java project that I have downloaded. Whatever jar files I'm adding I'm getting the same error message in the Eclipse console.

I have downloaded these following files to my project in Eclipse from

https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ :

[Java file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZnsP.jpg)

[Geckodriver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqGE9.jpg)

So I assume that these above files should be the latest ones?

However when Im running the small Java program below:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/Users/myName/Desktop/geckodriver");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin");

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get("http://www.google.com");


}
```

...Im getting the following error:

*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:146)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$000(GeckoDriverService.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.usingFirefoxBinary(GeckoDriverService.java:160)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.toExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:147)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:125)
    at test.SeleniumTest.main(SeleniumTest.java:14)*

These are the jars in my Build path:  [Build path in Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akjXM.jpg)

My Eclipse version: **Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)** 
My Firefox Version: **Firefox Quantum (69.0.34, 64-bit)** 
My Mac OS Version: **OS X El Capitan (10.11.6)**

Im still confused why because I just followed a lot of tutorials out there explaining it on how to achieve the automation test.

Did I just missed to add something to my project?

All help and advice would be highly appreciated

Comment: double-check path to geckdriver... also you can remove the client-combined...-source" dep.

Comment: one other thing is to be sure you have permissions set for the driver.  You can check by  if (!driver.canExecute())
           {
       driver.setExecutable (true, true);
           }

Comment: I could not find such methods in the API

Answer (score 0):

Read this [trouble ticket](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3880). You have an outdated version of guava.

Update guava [here](https://github.com/google/guava).

You should be able to add the guava JAR file to your Eclipse project by right clicking on the project name and selecting Build Path > Libraries > Add External JAR.

Comment: Ok thanks. Is there any possibility to add the latest guava as a standalone jar file. (I am not using Maven or Gradle)

Comment: The thing is that I changed the Guava version to 28 which should be the latest? But still the exact same kind of error appeared

Comment: @ErfanTavoosi What version of Java are you using in Eclipse? Window > Preferences > Installed JREs. Don't do a `java -version` from console because Eclipse maintains separate build paths for each project. And while we're on it, what else is in that project's build path? The error really only indicates that the JVM can't run your code, but it could be caused by some other dependency as well.

Comment: (Sorry I was not able to paste screenshots here)

**Installed JRE:**   

Java SE 10  



**Current jars on the Build path:**

activation.jar,

byte-buddy-1.8.15.jar,

client-combined-3.141.59-sources.jar,

client-combined-3.141.59.jar,

commons-exec-1.3.jar,

guava-28.0-jre.jar,

java-mail-1.4.4.jar,

okhttp-3.11.0.jar,

okio-1.14.0.jar,

opencsv-4.6.jar,

postgresql-42.2.8.jar,



twilio-7.5.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Comment: I will see if I can figure it out somehow. Thanks anyway for all your help!